# XGBoost: what's wrong with my xgb.cv call syntax?

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to use xgboost on Python.

Here is my code. `xgb.train` works but I get on error with `xgb.cv`
although it seems I used it the correct way.

The following works for me:

```
###### XGBOOST ######

import datetime
startTime = datetime.datetime.now()

import xgboost as xgb
data_train   = np.array(traindata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels_train = np.array(traindata['Category'].cat.codes)

data_valid   = np.array(validdata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels_valid = np.array(validdata['Category'].astype('category').cat.codes)

weights_train = np.ones(len(labels_train))
weights_valid  = np.ones(len(labels_valid ))

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data_train, label=labels_train,weight = weights_train)
dvalid  = xgb.DMatrix( data_valid , label=labels_valid ,weight = weights_valid )

param = {'bst:max_depth':5, 'bst:eta':0.05, # eta [default=0.3]
         #'min_child_weight':1,'gamma':0,'subsample':1,'colsample_bytree':1,'scale_pos_weight':0, # default
         # max_delta_step:0 # default
         'min_child_weight':5,'scale_pos_weight':0, 'max_delta_step':2,
         'subsample':0.8,'colsample_bytree':0.8,
         'silent':1, 'objective':'multi:softprob' }

param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'mlogloss'
param['lambda'] = 2
param['num_class']=39

evallist  = [(dtrain,'train'),(dvalid,'eval')] # if there is a validation set
# evallist  = [(dtrain,'train')]                   # if there is no validation set

plst = param.items()
plst += [('ams@0','eval_metric')]

num_round = 100

bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 ) # early_stopping_rounds=10 # when there is a validation set

# bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5)

bst.save_model('0001.model')

# dump model
bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt')
# dump model with feature map
# bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt','featmap.txt')

x = datetime.datetime.now() - startTime
print(x)
```

But if I change the line:

```
bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 )
```

to this:

```
bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

I get the following unexpected error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-46-ebdf0546f464>", line 45
>     bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5) SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after
> keyword arg
> ```

EDIT: 
following the advice below from @martineau, and trying this

```
bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,evallist,nfold = 5,early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

yields this error

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        43 # bst = xgb.train( plst, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 ) # early_stopping_rounds=10 # when
>   there is a validation set
>        44 
>   ---> 45 bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,evallist,nfold = 5,early_stopping_rounds=5)
>        46 
>        47 bst.save_model('0001.model')
>
> TypeError: cv() got multiple values for keyword argument 'nfold'

Comment: `evallist` should be keyword arg

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) it doesn't look like the call to `xgboost.train()` is correct because the first argument is supposed to be a `dict`, not a `list`. The same is true for `xgboost.cv()`. Regardless, from the error message you need to put all keyword arguments at the end of any function calls — so swap the order of `nfold = 5` & `evallist` in the list of calling arguments.

Comment: i tried it, it doesn't work (i edited the question)

Comment: I am also getting a keyword error when using xgb.cv() with the folds parameter. The Python API states that the 'folds' parameter can be used to set a custom Kfold. However, it produces this error: TypeError: cv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folds'

I am running it on an ec2 instance, using the latest xgb from pip. The same code works perfectly on my workstation, which is using a slightly older version of xgb. The Sklearn versions are the same on ec2 and workstation. I see that the verbose=false error was fixed recently, has the API changed? Thanks.

Comment: Any chances you could validate my answer?

Comment: sorry i havent had a look recently at this, i promise i will

Comment: Any chances you could validate my answer?

Comment: This was a package-version-specific issue, you should state the version, I think this was [0.6](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/releases)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `evallist` in `cv`.
So you should remove `evallist` from the arguments of the `xgb.cv` call.
Put another way, you should try:

`bst.res = xgb.cv(plst, dtrain, num_round, nfold=5, early_stopping_rounds=5)`

instead of

`bst.res=xgb.cv(plst,dtrain,num_round,nfold = 5,evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5)`

Chris,
the python training API slightly changed between the pip version and the current master branch in github. They mainly added the keyword args `verbose_eval`, `callbacks` and `folds` to the `cv` function. The `verbose_eval` and `callbacks` keywords were already there in the pip version for the `train` function but not for the `cv` one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, hopefully the OP will accept.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this error results from installing xgboost via pip, which is now out of date. XGBoost should instead be installed as follows:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; make -j4 
cd python-package; sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: whats the syntax for this under MacOS ?

Comment: Any chances you could validate my answer?

Comment: Hi Chris, I think you also started a bounty of 50 reputation points. I answered it in time...

Comment: Not sure how to award it now, if you know message me and I will do so.